# Bootstrap list-inline li elements are staggered

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the *list-inline* class of Bootstrap on an unordered list. I want to have all *li* elements the same size and to be perfectly aligned in rows.

I created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pmeo2eut/) to demonstrate the problem. You'll need to expand the preview area in order fully see the problem.

The expected behaviour is that each *li* element will have the same width and height and be in a row (all on the same level). The actual behaviour is that the li elements are staggered.

What is causing the elements to stagger?

*HTML*

## Documents

```
<ul class="list-inline box box20x25">
    <li>
        <p><i class="fa fa-home fa-fw"></i></p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Pteranodon was a flying reptile that lived during the time of the dinosaurs</p>
        <p class="description">Pteranodon was a flying reptile that lived during the time of the dinosaurs - it was not a dinosaur, but was a close relative of the dinosaurs. Pteranodon have three clawed fingers on each hand, and four clawed toes on each foot. Learn about Pteranodon, a.</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p class="title">Pteranodon was a flying reptile that lived during the time of the dinosaurs</p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

*CSS*

```
ul.box li {
    background: #000;
    color: #ccc;
}

ul.box20x25 li {
    height: 200px;
    width: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All that `list-inline` does is change the display of the list items to `display: inline-block;`. Since the vertical alignment of inline items defaults to baseline, you want to change that by setting the `vertical-align:top`.

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pmeo2eut/1/)**